# Two sources (S3 & Github) in codepipeline via CDK

Tags: aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild, aws-cdk

I am trying to build on the input of two sources GitHubSourceAction (sourceOutput) and S3SourceAction (source2_Output) and wire those in CDK/typescript via

```
    buildAction = new codepipeline_actions.CodeBuildAction({
        actionName: 'my_build',
        project: pipelineProject,
        input: sourceOutput,
        extraInputs: [source2_Output],
```

into one build process. But the filesystem of the fired up instance just sees the content of the first (primary) source.

Somehow extraInputs are not visible on the fs. Dont even know if extraInputs are designed for that. Wonder why input doesnt expect an array.

Has somebody an idea how to achieve it? I just need a merged codebase for my build step. Looking at the S3 artifact bucket, i have both ZIP (from both sources) in it but not during build.

Comment: A very useful way to troubleshoot this kind of issue is to look into the beginning of your failed codebuild logs. It will show you all the useful env vars created, included the ones that describe your source locations.

Comment: This is an awesome hint. I looked through the logs 1000 times but never at the beginning. Kind of a developer habbit to skip the header part ;-) Upvoted that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your buildspec in CodeBuild project should refer to the second artifact as follows:

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  build:
    commands:
      - touch source1_file
      - cd $CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR_source2_Output. # <================
      - touch source2_file
```

This is neatly described in AWS documentation as:

- AWS CodePipeline integration with CodeBuild and multiple input sources and output artifacts sample  - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/sample-pipeline-multi-input-output.html

Comment: but i made an "ls" in the commands section to see the filesystem in the logs and there is simply no file which resides in source2_Output. In fact its only a single file inside the ZIP in S3 and this should be placed in root folder right? Even if not, i also cant see a subfolder... If i just use source2_Output as primary Input, everything works and file is placed in root fs.

Comment: But perhaps shell starts in primary subfolder so that i dont see the other one. Let me check this and thanks so far for the input. I will come back to it soo.

Comment: shell starts at primary artifact subfolder and in fact you can just go to the subfolder which is the sister to "00" which is "01". Marked answer as correct.